# Segmentation Fault when trying to print Queue

Tags: c

I'm trying to print what I've stored in a queue using a singly linked list, the data was collected from input using fgets. The enqueue function is repeated 5 times. There is no issue collecting the data itself, at least, I don't think there is. But when I try to print it, the seg fault appears. My code is below:

In header file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define max 5

typedef struct MacroTreat{
  char name[30];
  char desc[200];
  struct MacroTreat *next;
} treat;

void enqueue (treat** front, treat** rear, treat* node);
void printQueue (treat* front);
```

In main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "headerfile.h"

int main() {

  int i;
  treat *front = NULL;
  treat *rear = NULL;
  treat *node = NULL;

  for(i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    enqueue(&front, &rear, node);
  }

  printQueue(front);

}
```

In queue file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "headerfile.h"
void enqueue (treat** front, treat** rear, treat* node) {

  int i;
  int size = 0;
  node = NULL;

  node = (treat*)malloc(sizeof(treat));

  printf("Enter the name of the treat: ");
  fgets(node->name, 30, stdin);
  //Get username
  printf("Enter its description: ");
  fgets(node->desc, 200, stdin);

  node->next = NULL;

  if((*rear)){
    (*rear)->next = node;
  }
  *rear = node;

  if(!(*front)) {
    *front = *rear;
  }
  size++;
  return;
}

void printQueue(treat* front) {

  int i;
  treat *node = NULL;

  for(i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    printf("%s: %s\n", node->name, node->desc);
    node = node->next;
  }

}
```

How do I actually print what's stored within the queue? Thanks

Comment: What's `start` in `printQueue`?

Comment: @Raswall What is tweet in declarations like this tweet *front = NULL;?

Comment: @Raswall The parameter front is not used in the function printQueue.

Comment: @Raswall The parameter node of the function enqueue does not make a sense,

Comment: My apologies, I've made the edits to make it less confusing, it seems I mistyped when writing my code into this.

Comment: In `printQueue()` you set `node=NULL` and then start accessing `node->name` etc. This will surely give a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

```
void printQueue(treat* front)
```

you set

```
treat *node = NULL;
```

and then reference:

```
node->name
```

node is NULL, hence the crash.
Maybe you intended to set

```
treat *node=front;
```

instead.
I'd also suggest adjusting your for statement to:

```
for(i = 0; node && i < max; i++)
```

So that once node becomes NULL (end of your link list). The loop terminates.